# Enable -98 in Hugs?

Tags: haskell, hugs

Whenever I start Hugs, it always says

```
Haskell 98 mode: Restart with command line option -98 to enable extensions
```

How exactly do you do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "start Haskell?" Which compiler and operating system are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're launching it from a command-line (Bash prompt, Windows Command Prompt, or the like), you would just change your command from `...` to `... -98`. (For example, if you've been running the command `haskell`, you would now run the command `haskell -98`.)

If you're launching it from a shortcut icon in Windows, such as a start-menu item, you have to modify that shortcut: right-click, select "Properties", and change "Target" from `...` (whatever it is now) to `... -98` (whatever it is now, plus a space, a hyphen, and ninety-eight).

Answer (score 1):

Well, just add `-98` as command line option ...

See [Hugs manual, section 7](http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/hugsman/exts.html).